# Is there a way to solve incorrect dates after conversion from objects?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Date         ID   Product
01/10/2018   01   XM0
01/10/2018   02   XM0
02/10/2018   02   BY2
```

The date is currently being recognised as an object so I run the following code to convert to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

For some reason when I run this line of code the output shows that the month of the date has been changed to January when it should be October:

```
Date         ID   Product
2018-01-10   01   XM0
2018-01-10   02   XM0
2018-02-10   02   BY2
```

Is there a way to prevent this so that the dates are accurately converted into the actual date when I run the datetime conversion line?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True`

**Ex:**

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True)
```